# Database entries modification history

Tags: php, serialization, storage, history

I am currently working on a big management system (in PHP using Zend Framework, but that is not really revelant of the solution to this question) in which I have to manage multiple entries. Each entry has many fields and span on two tables in a 1-to-many relationship (through a single foreign key). There is roughly 50 fields in the first table and 30 fields in the second one.

I am now at the stage to implement a history tracking of the different modifications made by users (and some automated tasks). Each entry might enventually be rolled back partially or totally to a previous value.

I was thinking about using a system similiar to the one present in the CMS Typo3. One table to manage the whole history with the following fields

- history_id
- entry_id
- entry_table
- last_modifcation_timestamp
- last_modification_user
- data

The data would be "serialized" in a json or xml format.

My concerns through this method is that overtime, the content of the history table would grow exponentially. To overcome this issue, I was thinking that i could make a new database to manage this history every years and then show history data by years to the users.

I am looking for advice about ways to improve this solution and ease the implementation. Any advice or documentation to help me will be welcome

Comment: Are you only serializing the old data, and assuming the most current version of the data is in the other tables?

Comment: @Chris : Yes, I am (was, I am not working on this project anymore). The most up to date data is the one in the original table. Over the time you might have schema difference from the history which would only give partial history if a lot of fields have changed

Comment: I'm considering how to implement history tracking/changes in some web apps I'm building (ironically using PHP/Zend Framework also).  I find this idea interesting.  I'm wondering, did you have to deal with compound entry ID's and how you resolved it?  I've got one table with a compound ID but I could easily just give it a surrogate or artificial ID.

Comment: No i did not had to use compound IDs but I would go the same way, with a surrogate ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add a threshold and remove or dump to an external file all entries older than a certain period of time.