# Keeping a revision history with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a couple tables that I want to keep a revision history on. What is the best way to accomplish this? It's going to be several fields (20 or so).

Should I create a duplicate table and just submit the old data to that? Should I use triggers? Or should I create a separate table and just track the changes made?

Comment: Do you want to revision your tables, or revision the data inside your tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the question I asked a few months back, but I would do it the same way again

[Database entries modification history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023414/database-entries-modification-history)

Comment: I thought about doing it this way and I probably will. Just wanted to see if there were any other options.

Comment: I do have one question about this. In the data field, are you only serializing the changed data or all the data? If it's only the changed data, how are you figuring out which data was actually changed?

Comment: I am serializing all the data before doing the update, that way it can accomodate table structure changes

Answer (score 5):

We're pretty happy with our choice which is using two tables per versioned entity.

Tables would look similar to this:

Table `person`:

- **id** (PK)
- **version** (counter for optimistic locking)
- **current** (foreign key referencing `person_version`)
- ... (any property that won't change)

Table `person_version`:

- **id** (PK)
- **person** (not null) (foreign key referencing `person`)
- **timestamp** (used for sorting)
- ... (any property that might change)

As entries in `person_version` won't ever change, it's easy to cache them (as long as there aren't any references to tables that might change)

Answer (score 3):

Some ORMs like [**Propel**](http://www.propelorm.org) can "natively" handle this frequent need.

Check the [**versionable behavior**](http://www.propelorm.org/behaviors/versionable).

- It automatically adds a **version** column to the "versioned" table (say **mytable**), and creates a **mytable_version** table (certainly containing columns **mytable_id** and **version**).
- It provides a simple API to query versioned tables. For example, When you do `$myobject->save();`, it automatically populates table **mytable_version** and updates field **mytable.version** accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add another column to your table which keeps track of the entry-id, while the active PK then is the revision-id. The one with the highest revision-id is the latest and active record, the other entries with the same entry-id are the previous revisions.

Comment: I was going to do that but the problem is there are other tables that are linked to the primary key of this table. So if I insert a new row, the relationships would break.